# How to find a string from text file by using regex python3?

Tags: python, regex

> How to find a word by using regex?
>
> file.txt

```
CLIENT BILL
BILL
FINAL BILL
TOTAL BILL
```

> python code

```
  import re
  with open('file.txt','r') as f: 
     input_file = f.readlines()

 for i in input_file:
     s = re.findall(r'L/sBILL',i)
     print(s)
```

> Expected Output:

```
 FINAL BILL
 TOTAL BILL
```

Comment: What is `L/SBILL` supposed to mean? Right now, that regex matches exactly the string `"L/SBILL"` and nothing else.

Comment: L space BILL regex term

Comment: That would be `L\sBILL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.match` for this, with another pattern:

```
for i in input_file:
   if re.match('\w+(s|L) BILL', i.rstrip()):
      print(i.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
FINAL BILL
TOTAL BILL
```

Comment: @pythoncoder Happy to help :-) remember to accept if it works :-)

Comment: See OP's comment above: `L\sBILL` is what he/she actually wanted. Otherwise `THIS BILL` would also match.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Edited my answer

Comment: That will still match `This BILL` and fails `SUB-TOTAL BILL` (which might be what OP wants, they didn't say - they did say they wanted `L <space> BILL` to match, and that would be `L\sBILL` or `L BILL` (if only an actual space should match)).